# Get Json from asp.net errors

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, webforms

`<script>...
      data: [

                        <%=ser%>, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1]
...
    </script>`

CODE BEHIND

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
ser = serializer.Serialize(list);
```

The variable ser is not working like the number 1 manual inputed, why?

OUTPUT

```
ser = "[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49]";
```

Comment: I dont know if need more information but anyway, I can edit.

Comment: Maybe try the <%# %> tags instead? And yeah, we need a lot more information. Post all the code. When you start mixing JavaScript and ASP.Net nuggets, the quotation marks and everything become really important, so please post your whole code - the ASP.Net parser might be failing on something. Also, please say what the code actually does, and why that is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Last try

```
[<%=ser%>]
```

Inside code

```
ser = ser.Substring(1, ser.Length - 2);
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: If you answer your own question, please write something like I found a solution. If this is an additional question, please kindly edit the original question.